# RewriteRule get error when i call xajax

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

like a title i have a problem with this rewrite rule
I write this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(font|css|js|images|remote) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(font|css|js|images|remote/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index$     /page/index         [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /page/article&category=$1&post=$2   [QSA,L]
```

When i call ajax remote from /remote/check-function.php from pages he load full /page/post with variable sent by ajax.

How i can resolve this issue

Thanks in advance.
Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteCond` only applies to the `RewriteRule` that comes immediately. Properly that the url `/remote/check-function.php` matches the last rule and is rewritten. You should add `RewriteCond` to check whether the request matches the existing files / directories before applying the last rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /page/article&category=$1&post=$2   [QSA,L]
```